# problems with imported texture

Tags: unity, textures, import, gimp

I have done a texture in GIMP and imported it in Unity but for some reason the texture appears to be squashed in the sides.

Image done in gimp:

[image]

And here is what happens in Unity:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use it as sprite then change the import settings 'Texture Type' to 'Sprite(2D and UI)'. This will bring it back to its original dimensions. If you want to use it as texture then this wont matter, the texture depends upon the 3d object UV mapping, so it will scale properly.

For particle you can convert the entire image to have square dimensions.
Like this:-
[image]

Comment: Thnx for replying but what should I do if I would like to use it for particle system?

Comment: Convert the texture to square dimensions , so that it wont get skewed :)